# jQuery data table method fnSetColumnVis is not showing check box

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable

I am using Following datable property to hide one column.

```
data.aoColumnDefs = [ {
 "bVisible": false, 
 "aTargets": [ 9 ] 
}];
```

This column has check boxes in each row. To add check boxes I am calling following method on each row which is working fine.

```
_buildCheckBox : function() {
    var newScriptElement = $("<input type='checkbox' class='re-execute-check' />");
        return $('<div>').append(newScriptElement.eq(0).clone()).html(); 
    }
```

Later on in one condition I am trying to show this column by using fnSetColumnVis method.

```
 var table = this._resultsTable.dataTable();
 table.fnSetColumnVis(9, true);
```

With this I can see column but check boxes are not displaying for each row. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can any one help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

render checkboxes when drawing table using [mRender parameter](http://datatables.net/ref#mRender):

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full) {
     return data + ' <input type='checkbox' class='re-execute-check' />';
}
```

or

just call your method after showing hide column.